# File can't be read when debugging in PyCharm, but works when running normally

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have the following code:

```
if os.path.exists('asdf.txt'):
    with open('asdf.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

asdf.txt contains: `test`

If I run the file normally, the contents will be printed to the console. However, if I put a break point in the print line, it will just print an empty line. The debugger reports the contents of f as `''`

What could be happening? My PyCharm version is:

```
PyCharm 2023.2.1 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-232.9559.58, built on August 22, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.8+7-b1000.8 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

I tried disabling cython speedups for debugging, but it didn't work.
Surprisingly, when I add a pass after the print statement and break at the added line so that the print statement is not interrupted, the contents are printed as expected, so something is happening during the pausing of the print statement by the debugger.

Update: If I do `import json` before executing the print statement, the bug presents itself. But if not imported, the print statement behaves as expected.

Why would the debugger stop working with a simple file import due to the importation of the json module from the standard library?

Comment: That's a relative path name and the current working directory for pycharm is likely different than whatever "normally" is. You could add `print(os.path.abspath("asdf.txt"))` to the code and try it in both environments to see if you have the same file.

Comment: @tdelaney The path is the same in both cases: the bug presents itself only when the break point is directly on the print line. If the break happens after it, it will print the file contents without issues.

Comment: I don't use pycharm and don't know the specifics of how it does things like inspect variables. When you said "The debugger reports the contents of f as ''", it got me wondering whether the debugger would read the file to display its contents. At end of file, it would read an empty line. `import json` should not have any affect on an existing file - that is very odd behavior.